# Can't remove child from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I have a to-do list app that uses a listView and I can manage to send a "task" to firebase and then show it in my app but I can not manage to remove a specific task from firebase.

I tried using `.push()` method to send data to firebase but I couldn't manage to retrieve it so I am now using `.setValue()`. I am using the task title as a subchild in firebase and this is what I am trying to delete.

```
Intent myIntent = getIntent();
String email = myIntent.getExtras().getString("email");

public void addToDoElement(View view) {
    String title = mTitle.getText().toString();
    String content = mContent.getText().toString();
    task friendlyTask = new task(title, content);
    mTasksDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child(email).child("tasks").child(title);
        mTasksDatabaseReference.setValue(friendlyTask);

}

public void deleteTask(View view) {
    TextView itemTitle = findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    String childToDelete = itemTitle.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted task: " + childToDelete, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    mTasksDatabaseReference.child(email).child("tasks").child(childToDelete).setValue(null);    //I am trying to delete the task title from firebase so that the entire task will be removed
```

This is what the firebase looks like. for example, when I try to delete the second task (Task title 2) nothing happens

[image: This is what my firebase project looks like]

Comment: Can you try if you can reproduce the problem with a single statement with hardcoded values. So `mTasksDatabaseReference.child("???@yahoo.com").child("tasks").child("Task title 1").setValue(null);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `addToDoElement` you initialize `mTasksDatabaseReference` to:

```
mTasksDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child(email).child("tasks").child(title);
```

You then use `mTasksDatabaseReference` in `deleteTask` to delete the child.

```
mTasksDatabaseReference.child(email).child("tasks").child(childToDelete).setValue(null);
```

But since you already set `mTasksDatabaseReference` as a reference to the specific task, you're now trying to point to a task under another task.

```
public void deleteTask(View view) {
    TextView itemTitle = findViewById(R.id.task_title);
    String childToDelete = itemTitle.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted task: " + childToDelete, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child(email).child("tasks").child(childToDelete).setValue(null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I managed to understand what I was doing wrong thanks to your code and now I cand manage to remove a child from my database. 
What's still wrong, is the fact that no matter what ListView element I try to delete, it will always delete the first element in the list (e.g.: When I try to delete "Task title 2" it removes "Task title 1" as it is the first element in the list). 
P.S.: Check the picture in my question to understand the given example

Comment: I did, could you also help me with my second problem or should I do another post ?

Comment: That second problem makes no sense to me. You might want to open a new question, and share the [minimal standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) there. I always recommend using only hardcoded values to reproduce the problem. If you can't reproduce it that way, you know the problem isn't in the code you're trying to share.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
mTasksDatabaseReference.child(email).child("tasks").child(childToDelete).removeValue();
```

instead of the **setValue(null)**

Comment: Calling `setValue(null)` on a location accomplishes the same as calling `removeValue()` on that location. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#delete_data, which says "You can also delete by specifying null as the value for another write operation such as `setValue()` or `updateChildren()`."

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
private void deleteOrder(String key) {
    requests.child(key).removeValue();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Where requests is the database reference and adapter is the Firebase Recycler Adapter**